# What does ‘defiled’ mean in Mark 7:5?

Tags: jesus, gospels, torah, purity-laws

In Mark 7:5, we see the accusation that Jesus and His disciples eat food with defiled hands:

> “So the Pharisees and teachers of the law asked Jesus, “Why don’t your disciples live according to the tradition of the elders instead of eating their food with defiled hands?””
> ‭‭Mark‬ ‭7:5‬ ‭NIV‬‬

In Matthew:

> ““Why do your disciples break the tradition of the elders? They don’t wash their hands before they eat!””
> ‭‭Matthew‬ ‭15:2‬ ‭NIV‬‬

How should the word ‘defiled’ be understood in these passages?

Do the accusations refer to physical hygiene and defilement? a lack of ritual / spiritual cleanliness? or both?

Answer (score 1):

Both in Mark 7:5 (KJV) and Matthew 15:2 (KJV) refers to unwashed hands (physical). There was a tradition among the Israelites that one should wash their hands before eating.

Mark 7:5 KJV

> Then the Pharisees and scribes asked him, Why walk not thy disciples according to the tradition of the elders, but eat bread with unwashen hands?

Matthew 15:2 KJV

> Why do thy disciples transgress the tradition of the elders? for they wash not their hands when they eat bread.

In the succeeding verses in Matthew 15:3 where Jesus told them (the Pharisees) that washing hands is a tradition, and how Israel is so stubborn in their own tradition, that they are disregarding/transgressing the commandments of the Lord. (parallel verse in Mark 7:8)

Also eating with unwashen hands does not make a person sinful as written in Matthew 15:10-11 (KJV)

> <sup>**10**</sup>And he called the multitude, and said unto them, Hear, and understand:  <sup>**11**</sup> Not that which goeth into the mouth defileth a man; but that which cometh out of the mouth, this defileth a man. (parallel verse in Mark 7:14-15)

Answer (score 1):

The record we have of this incident uses three different words to describe the same thing:

- Matt 15:2 - οὐ νίπτονται = not washed, and
- Matt 15:20 - ἄνιπτος = unwashed
- Mark 7:2, 5 - κοινός = common (literally), profane; dirty, unclean (ritually), and
- Matt 7:2 - ἄνιπτος = unwashed

That is, in this instance, "common" meant "unwashed" or "unclean", etc.

The primary objection of the Jews here is stated explicitly in matt 15:2:

> “Why do Your disciples **break the tradition** of the elders? They do
> not wash their hands before they eat.”

Mark explains this more fully:

> Mark 7:2-5 - and they saw some of His disciples eating with hands that
> were **defiled**—that is, **unwashed**. Now in holding to the
> tradition of the elders, the Pharisees and all the Jews do not eat
> until they **wash their hands ceremonially**. And on returning from
> the market, they do not eat unless they wash. And there are many
> **other traditions for them to observe**, including the washing of cups, pitchers, kettles, and couches for dining. So the Pharisees and
> scribes questioned Jesus: “Why do Your disciples not walk according to
> **the tradition of the elders**? Instead, they eat with **defiled hands**.”

Thus, there was no question here of hygiene but purely that of ceremonial cleanness as defined by the tradition of the elders.